I am experimenting with Prisma, but the auto-suggest of data in VS Code isn't working as intended
I am trying to learn Prisma. Suppose I am trying to find the different operations that could be done on a database, so I press ctrl+space for options but I am not finding any option which I need, I am getting those words suggestion I have used earlier. I have to manually type the function by myself in VS Code:

I have tried closing and reopening VS Code and updating it to the latest version as well.
I am watching a Youtube tutorial and this is how I expect ctrl+space to be working.

I have the Prisma extension installed.
What is the possible fix for it? Is it a problem with Prisma or with VS Code?

Have you generated your Prisma client?
